# Return byte[] and string in Spring

Tags: java, javascript, spring, spring-mvc, backbone.js

I'm trying to use Java Spring in conjunction with Backbone.js. I am executing a search in some backend and receiving a token from that object along with a string. I want to return that string AND that object because I want that object to persist (I need to use it later).

One idea I had was to serialize the object and then take the resulting byte[] and change it to a String and then return that along with my other data(possibly in a json object). Will I then be able to convert that string back to the object by changing it to a byte[], or will that not work because it will simply convert that string to the byte[] representation of the string, as opposed to the object?

If so, then how can I use Spring to return both a JSON object and a byte[]?

Thanks

Comment: How is that object parsed from the `byte[]`, what object is it? Can one inject any Java object into your application by sending it a string?

Answer (score 0):

You can find plenty of tutorials on how to return JSON-encoded data from a Spring MVC application just by googling "Spring MVC tutorial json".

Returning data from your Java app encoded as a byte array generated by Java serialization doesn't sound like a good idea if you intend to use that data in a JavaScript application. How can you deserialize a Java-serialized stream of bytes in a non-Java environment? Just stick to cross-platform, cross-language encodings like JSON.

Comment: So currently I'm hitting java to make backend calls, I need to make a certain object persist because I need to use it for future backend calls. So I get a search request from front end, I execute the corresponding API call, get this object and a set of results, I need to send them both back because I need this object for future search request- I need to make it persist beyond the scope of the java program

Comment: So you want to pass back a `byte[]` encoded as a String that the client has to pass to the server in subsequent requests? I'm not sure what the point of that would be - why not just return some sort of ID that you can map back to the object within your app? This sounds easier - and less data to transport over the wire - than a large base64-encoded string that must be passed around like a token. How will you deal with someone potentially tampering with this token's value and sending you back something malicious?